# ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints: so:libvpx.so.6 (missing)

Tags: ffmpeg, dockerfile, alpine-linux, alpine-package-keeper

FFMpeg was updated this week and is causing the build to break.

Are my options to either:

1. pin ffmpeg to a previous version? If so, how do I pin to the version before current?
2. Update the python dockerfile version

Output:

```
Step 8/42 : RUN apk add  --no-cache ffmpeg
 ---> Running in 9e46540ed393
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-8.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  so:libvpx.so.6 (missing):
    required by:
                 ffmpeg-libs-4.1.1-r2[so:libvpx.so.6]
                 ffmpeg-libs-4.1.1-r2[so:libvpx.so.6]
                 ffmpeg-libs-4.1.1-r2[so:libvpx.so.6]
                 ffmpeg-libs-4.1.1-r2[so:libvpx.so.6]
                 ffmpeg-libs-4.1.1-r2[so:libvpx.so.6]
                 ffmpeg-libs-4.1.1-r2[so:libvpx.so.6]
                 ffmpeg-libs-4.1.1-r2[so:libvpx.so.6]
                 ffmpeg-libs-4.1.1-r2[so:libvpx.so.6]
                 ffmpeg-libs-4.1.1-r2[so:libvpx.so.6]
                 ffmpeg-libs-4.1.1-r2[so:libvpx.so.6]
The command '/bin/sh -c apk add  --no-cache ffmpeg' returned a non-zero code: 3
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 3
FATAL: exit code 3
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6.7-alpine

ENV LANG C.UTF-8
RUN echo "http://dl-8.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community" >> /etc/apk/repositories
RUN apk upgrade


RUN addgroup -S django && adduser -S -G django django

RUN apk update
# FFMPEG/Sox dependencies
RUN apk add sox
#RUN apk add  --no-cache libvpx-dev
RUN apk add  --no-cache ffmpeg
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only adding the `community` edge repository, not `main`. This leads to some inconsistencies for apk.

It works if you change your Dockerfile:4 to the following:

```
RUN echo -e "http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community\nhttp://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main" >> /etc/apk/repositories
```

Comment: Awesome! This helped me fix a similar problem in my own project :)